# Refreshing SharePoint site cause the site page to go to top of window while updating at the bottom

Tags: sharepoint

we recently came across an issue that while working on the SharePoint site, when scroll down to bottom of the page, site refresh causes the SharePoint site to get back to the top of the site thus making an issue. Is there any way to solve this type of issues in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Is there RichHTML field on the page? If you have one this causes setting focus on that field and no way to change this...